# Stuck in cryptsetup

Tags: xfce, cryptsetup

I have installed xfce Desktop once, more or less as a second desktop. Today I wanted to uninstall it. It worked. But now, after I entered my password correctly in cryptsetup, nothing happens. I have two monitors and normally it is on the right one, but after I entered the password correctly it is also on the left one and nothing else happens. I use POP OS

Comment: Ok, so many questions here...first of all, I'm not sure Pop!_OS is on-topic here. Apart from that, what are you trying to open with cryptsetup? A partition? A container? Are you using full disk encryption and are trying to log into your OS? When you say "normally it is on the right one", what is "it"?

Comment: PopOS is off-topic.